# How to pass a closure to a function from a method on a struct that has a lifetime parameter in Rust?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I have a struct Foo with a lifetime parameter 'a:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
  /* snip */
}
```

I want to pass a closure (which encloses some of Foo's fields) to an arbitrary function, for example:

```
impl Foo<'_> {

  // ...

  pub fn do_something(&mut self) {
    self.some_object.do_something(
      Box::new(
        |a_parameter| {
          self.some_other_object.do_something_else(a_parameter);
        }
      )
    );
  }

  // ...

}
```

do_something would be defined something like so:

```
fn do_something(f: Box<dyn Fn(T)>) { /* snip */ }
```

The error I get is

```
cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

Where '1 is the lifetime of the mutable reference to self in the function implemented on Foo itself.

I think the problem is that I need to specify that the closure (inside the box) lives precisely as long as the function (i.e., the scope) in which it is defined. I just don't see how to do this, I tried numerous things, e.g., adding a lifetime parameter to do_something, though, no success.

Thanks!

**Edit**

a (non working) example:

```
struct Bar {
  num: i32,
} 
impl Bar {
  fn do_something(&self, f: Box<dyn Fn(i32)>) {
    f(self.num);
  }
}

struct Foo<'a> {
  bar: &'a Bar,
  other_num: i32,
}

impl Foo<'_> {

  fn do_something(&self) {
    self.bar.do_something(
      Box::new(|n| {
        println!("{}", n + self.other_num);
      })
    );
  }

}


fn main() {
 
  let bar = Bar { num: 123, };
  let foo = Foo { bar: &bar, other_num: 456, };

  foo.do_something();

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, just did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you take the closure as a trait object (`Box<dyn Fn(i32)>`), there's an implicit `+ 'static` bound (`Box<dyn Fn(i32) + 'static>`), meaning the closure isn't allowed to borrow any data. But the closure you want to pass borrows from `&self`. You can make the parameter more general by using an explicit lifetime:

```
impl Bar {
    fn do_something<'a>(&self, f: Box<dyn Fn(i32) + 'a>) {
    //             ^^^^                          ^^^^^^
    // `f` is now allowed to borrow data for any lifetime `'a`
        f(self.num);
    }
}
```

which can be elided

```
impl Bar {
    fn do_something(&self, f: Box<dyn Fn(i32) + '_>) {
        f(self.num);
    }
}
```

This is a really simple example. In more complex code, the lifetime requirements might be more strict than this.

Comment: Yes, this does the trick, awesome. Any thoughts on the Box? A lot of high level languages with "lambda's" would allow you to simple pass |x| { ... } and without any lifetime shenanigans.

Comment: The `Box` is actually the reason you need the lifetime bound. If `do_something` had the signature `fn do_something(&self, f: impl Fn(i32))` it'd work without the annotation.

Comment: **And** you wouldn't need to `Box` the closure, avoiding an allocation.

Comment: Hm, ok, I see. I tried doing impl Fn(...), but this seems to open a whole can of worms again. Foo should actually be a trait, zhich results in an error that it cannot be made into an object (when stored as &'a dyn Foo, also because there should be a type parameter T, Foo<T>). Regardless, thanks for the help. :)